# can not find Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, please help me

Tags: c#, excel, classnotfoundexception, office-automation

in my c# program, i try to use wrtie something to excel.
i find a method on the internet, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel class.
but when i use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel,it said that no Interop class found.
i have already had Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library reference in my project

Comment: Could you show your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` to your project. See the example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx